# Dollar sign before self declaring anonymous function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function, iife

What is the difference between these two:

```
$(function () {
    // do stuff
});
```

AND

```
(function () {
    // do stuff
})();
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The first uses jQuery to bind a function to the `document.ready` event.  The second declares and immediately executes a function.

Comment: Ah ok, so the major difference is that the second one doesn't wait for the document to finish loading, and just executes immediately?

Comment: @xil3 - correct.  The first one is appropriate if the function needs to modify the DOM.  The second is useful if you just need the effects of the JS.  Rarely the two are interchangeable, but typically the former is preferable because most jQuery code is used to manipulate DOM elements.

Answer (score 26):

`$(function() {});` is a jQuery shortcut for

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
     /* Handler for .ready() called. */ 
 });
```

While `(function() {})();` is a instantly invoked function expression, or IIFE.  This means that its an expression (not a statement) and it is invoked instantly after it is created.

Comment: *self executing anonymous function

Comment: I'd prefer to see them called "immediately invoked" rather than "self executing" or "self-invoking". For example, `(function () { arguments.callee() })()` would be a "self executing/invoking anonymous function" while `(function(){})()` is just an anonymous function that is invoked immediately. See: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/#iife

Answer (score 5):

one is a jquery `$(document).ready` function and the other is just an anonymous function that calls itself.

Comment: That is not actually a closure.  Just a self-invoking anonymous function.  Neither of them are closures.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 5):

They are both anonymous functions, but `(function(){})()` is called immediately, and `$(function(){})` is called when the document is ready.

jQuery works something like this.

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = function(arg) {
    if (typeof arg == 'function') {
        // call arg() when document is ready
    } else {
       // do other magics
    }
}
```

So you're just calling the jQuery function and passing in a function, which will be called on document ready.

The 'Self-executing anonymous function' is the same as doing this.

```
function a(){
    // do stuff
}
a();
```

The only difference is that you are not polluting the global namespace.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function () {
    // It will invoked after document is ready
});
```

This function execution once documents get ready mean, the whole HTML should get loaded before its execution but in the second case, the function invoked instantly after it is created.

```
(function () {
    // It will invoked instantly after it is created
})();
```