# start javascript code with $(function, etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am studying Backbone and the todo example apps from http://todomvc.com/
I have noticed there are 3 severals ways of starting the code in the files:

```
$(function() {
 // code here
});

$(function( $ ) {
 // code here
});

(function() {
 // code here
}());
```

I do not understand the differences and when I should use one over the other.

I also saw some people using this to start their code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // code here
});
```

From what I have seen, this is  the full way of writing it right?

In a more general way, should I always include my javascript code into something like that in each files?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: The third example is **not** equivalent to the others.

Comment: See also [Dollar sign before self declaring anonymous function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614574/dollar-sign-before-self-declaring-anonymous-function-in-javascript]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

1. `$(document).ready(function(){})` ensures that your code runs on DOM ready, so that you have access to the DOM. You can read more about this in [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).
2. `$(function(){})` is just an alias to #1. Any code in here will wait for DOM ready ([see the docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)).
3. `$(function($){})` is equivalent to #1 and #2, only you get a clean reference to jQuery in the [local scope](http://skilldrick.co.uk/2011/04/closures-explained-with-javascript/) (see the note below). You can likewise pass in `$` to the function in #1, and it'll do the same thing (create a local reference to jQuery).
4. `(function(){}())` is just a [self-executing-anonymous-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript), used to create a new closure.

Please note that none of these are specific to Backbone. The first 3 are specific to jQuery, while #4 is just vanilla JavaScript.

---

**Note:** To understand what's going on in #3 above, remember that `$` is an alias to `jQuery`. However, jQuery is not the only library that uses the `$` variable. Since the `$` might be overwritten by someone else, you want to ensure that within your scope, `$` will always reference jQuery - hence the `$` argument.

---

In the end, it basically boils down to the following 2 options:

1. If your JavaScript is loaded in the `head`, you have to wait for document ready, so use this:

   ```
   jQuery(function($) {
       // Your code goes here.
       // Use the $ in peace...
   });
   ```
2. If you load your JavaScript at the bottom of your document (before the closing body tag - [which you should definitely be doing](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html/#js_bottom)), then there's no need to wait for document ready (since the DOM is already constructed by the time the parser gets to your script), and a [SEAF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript) (A.K.A. [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)) will suffice:

   ```
   (function($) {
       // Use the $ in peace...
   }(jQuery));
   ```

---

**P.S.** For a good understanding of Closures and Scope, see [**JS101: A Brief Lesson on Scope**](http://dailyjs.com/2012/07/23/js101-scope/).

Comment: Just to avoid confusion (and rage in some) self-executing-anonymous-function don't really execute themselves.. they have been coined this but are really [Immediately Invoked Functions](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).   **and** after posting this I *Immediately*  saw the little footnote about (A.K.A IIFE) so nvm :P It is funny how we both linked to the same article though.

Comment: @rlemon - While I agree with Cowboy (Ben Alman) that **immediatly-invoked-function-expression** is the more accurate term, **self-executing-anonymous-function** has become the standard way to refer to them. We both linked to the same article because that is the source for the **IIFE** name. P.S. That article is worth a read regardless of what you call 'em. It has some great info on these function expressions.

Comment: Ohh I've already read it, and I personally do not care what we call them, so long as people know how they function and why to use them. I just was doing my due diligence and linking it :P but It was all for not :P you already had :) I like IIFE only because it is more accurate and SEAF is a ugly acronym.

Comment: @rlemon - I wouldn't say that SEAF is an ugly acronym. But when it comes to their pronunciation... Come on! Nothing beats "iffy" :P

Comment: @JosephSilber: Do you realize that your use of a numbered list containing references by number makes this confusing to read? You say `2. ... is just an alias to #1.` and `3. ... is equivalent to #2 ...` This makes it look like `$(document).ready(function(){})` and `$(function(){})` and `$(function($){})` are all kinda the same. If some of those numbers refer to the un-numbered examples in the OP's question then your answer will surely benefit from a bit of clarification. - **OR** it could be that I'm the confused one! Either way I'm sure it can be clarified to rule out the wrong interpretation

Comment: @hippietrail - Those 3 *are* all kinda the same. I don't see what would make any of this confusing. The only thing I can think of is that the order is different than in the original question, but I had to switch them around in order to explain it properly.

Comment: @JosephSilber: Actually I had no idea that `$(function(){})` implied waiting for document ready! So I thought there must've been another way to read your answer. I'm not sure if I'm the only one so dumb ...

Comment: @hippietrail - [Read the docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) (linked to in the answer). Search for "All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent". I updated my answer a bit. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @JosephSilber now it's clear even to us dummies! (-: And thanks also for the jQuery documentation link that says so too.

Answer (score 18):

I guess it makes sense to start out, by realizing that `$ = jQuery`. The purpose of which down below when reading about namespaces within anonymous functions will make more sense. But in essence, you can use either of them. One would use `jQuery()` instead of `$()` if they were using multiple libraries, and wanted the `$` to be used by the other one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Here we have jQuery(document) firing off the ready event
    // which executes once the DOM has been created in 
    // order to ensure that elements you are trying to manipulate exist.
});

​$(function () {
    // Short-hand version of $(document).ready(function () { });
});
```

[**More information on Document.ready()**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Putting the **`$`** within the parenthesis ensures the **jQuery $ alias** (you can be safe it always signifies jQuery this way).

```
$(function ($) { /* code here : $ always means jQuery now */ });
```

Lastly you have an **IIFE (Immidiately-Invoked Function Expression)**
- [IIFE explanation](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

```
(function (myNameSpace, $) {
    // This is an anonymous function - it is ran instantly
    // Usually used for namespaces / etc
    // This creates a scope/wrapper/closure around everything inside of it
}(window.myNameSpace, jQuery));
```

The $ at the top (with it's matching jQuery on the bottom) signify that the
$ (dollar sign) stands for jQuery within the scope of the namepsace.
This is done to ensure that other libraries do not collide with what the developer
intends/wants the $ to be used with.

```
(function (myNameSpace, $) {
    // Now because of all of this scope/wrapper/closure awesome...
    // you can create -INTERNAL- variables (sort of like Private variables from other langs) 
    // this variable cannot be accessed outside the namespace unless it is returned / exposed

    var internalVariable = '123'; // Internal

    // Even Internal functions!
    function privateFunction () {
        console.log('this is private!');
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------
    // Public -method- of nameSpace exposing a private variable
    // Notice we're using the myNameSpace object we exposed at the top/bottom

    myNameSpace.nameSpaceMethod = function () {
        privateFunction(); // we can call the private function only inside of the namespace
        return internalVariable; // now we could get this variable
    };
}(window.myNameSpace, jQuery)); // notice these mirror the above arguments in the anon function
```

[**More information on anonymous functions**](http://helephant.com/2008/08/23/javascript-anonymous-functions/)

Now if we're **outside of the namespace**, we can see how these internal/public methods and variables are effected:

```
// This will come up undefined
alert(internalVariable);

// This will trigger a -method- of the myNameSpace namespace - and alert "123"
// Showcasing how we access a Public method - which itself has access to the internal variable
// and exposes it to us!
alert(myNameSpace.nameSpaceMethod());
​
```

Answer (score 2):

These two:

```
$(function() {
 // code here
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  // code here
});
```

Are directly equivalent, they are both the way to start some jQuery when the document has loaded. The former is just a shorter version of the latter.

This one:

```
(function() {
 // code here
}());
```

is just a scoped function with zero parameters, which is immediately called with zero parameters.