# jQuery plugin's syntax is too strange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little trouble about the meaning of syntax "(function( $ )" and "(jQuery)" in the below code.

```
(function( $ ){
$.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    // Do your awesome plugin stuff here
};})(jQuery);
```

Can you please explain what meaning of them ?

If I want to change phrase "(jQuery)" in the above code to "(abc)" then how to do it and how to use it ?

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: If you change `jQuery` to `abc` then `$` inside the closure will be the value of `abc` instead of `jQuery`. If `abc` is undefined `$.fn.myPlugin` will give an error.

Comment: And why do you want to change that to abc anyhow?

Comment: Your question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484289/id-like-to-understand-the-jquery-plugin-syntax).

Comment: @bertl whoa, and answered by Joel himself!

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008843/start-javascript-code-with-function-etc/12008894#12008894

Answer (score 1):

`function($)` says that the function takes a single parameter, the variable `$`, which (like any parameter) is accessible inside the function.

The `$.fn.myPlugin` is making use of that parameter.

The `(function...)(jQuery)` is making a function block that automatically gets invoked, passing `jQuery` as the parameter.

The point in doing this is making sure that the `$` alias people usually use to represent jQuery actually is passed a jQuery object, and not any other variable named `$`.

There's no good reason to change `jQuery` to `abc`, unless you have a `jQuery` instantiation in the variable `abc`.

Answer (score 1):

It is an immediately invoked function expression. It allows you to 1) enclose code in such a way that any variables are limited to its scope rather than polluting the window environment, and 2) to pass in parameters you can use in your code.

In this case `Jquery` is passed in as `$` so you can use `$` safe in the knowledge that you can use `$` without it conflicting with any other libraries that might use it as an alias.

You can certainly pass in `abc` as well as `jQuery` assuming `abc` exists.

```
(function($, abc) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
   console.log(abc);
  }
}(jQuery, abc));
```