# jquery- is document.ready necessairry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make use of JS module (iffys) in order to structure my JS functions. I'm using jQuery and pure JS. My JS modules are loaded at the end of the HTML body, so the page shall be loaded and rendered.

Is a document.ready necessairry closure?
How do I have to put it, if I'm working with iffys?

JS Module

```
app.input = (function () {
    var updateSize = function (data) {.....
    }
    $(".tool").click(function () {....
    });
    return {
        updateSize: updateSize,
    }
})();
```

Comment: `document.ready()` is not required if your code is after the elements it references.

Comment: check this answer [start javascript code with $(function, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008843/start-javascript-code-with-function-etc)