# Jsfiddle Error createDocumentFragment undefined

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, jsfiddle

When I create a demo to page load progress bar 
I am getting document.createDocumentFragment(); undefined in the jsFiddle

Jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/t3XTn/3/)

```
 <h1>Gallery Progress Bar</h1>
 <div id="main"></div>
 <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had your first function out of  `(function($){//your code})(jQuery);`

I've put it inside but now I get "img not defined" error because it is undefined.

I suppose Your script should wait till the DOM is fully loaded in order to work properly.

This post can come in hand: [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008843/start-javascript-code-with-function-etc)

Here is the fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3XTn/5/)