# How best to say "execute this code on document ready"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I was first learning JavaScript, I sort of picked up the habit of wrapping any scripts I wanted to execute the moment the page loaded inside a construct like this:

```
$(function() {
    //code
});
```

Having learned more since then, I'm under the impression I could just as easily toss the jQuery and write:

```
(function(){
    //code
})();
```

Are these two methods equivalent in end result? Is one preferable? Am I entirely mistaken about one or both? What is the standard best practice for "execute on document ready"?

Comment: No they are doing different things. The second one doesn't wait for the DOM to be ready.

Comment: possible duplicate of [start javascript code with $(function, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008843/start-javascript-code-with-function-etc)

Answer (score 6):

They're not the same thing at all. The first is a `document.ready` event, that typically looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(fn);
```

But jQuery lets you use a shortcut:

```
$(fn);
```

The second code is an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), all it does is create a closure, so you don't expose variables to the global scope, then executes itself right away.

When you use jQuery, putting all your code in a ready event is good practice, an incidentally you create a closure too, so everything in there is "private" too. But you don't need the ready event, if you add the code before your closing `body` tag. You can use as many IIFEs as you want, but you typically only use one ready event, since the event only runs once.

In conclusion, `document.ready` triggers when the event occurs. IIFEs let you encapsulate code.

Answer (score 1):

The first one waits for document ready, so use it if you put your code in the `head` of the document.

Use the second method ([IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)) if you put all of your JavaScript at the bottom of the page ([which you should anyhow be doing](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/high-performance-sites-rule-6-move-scripts-bottom-7200.html)).

---

There's also a good practice of passing jQuery into that function:

```
(function ($) {
    // code
}(jQuery));
```

...so that in case another library has overwritten the global `$` variable, you can still safely use it within the IIFE.

Comment: I think the shortcut `jQuery(function($){...})` will be shorter and nice

Comment: @ArunPJohny - But that's extra logic that you don't need, and also delays the execution (though just by a negligible amount).